# array except other

Tags: python

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = [a,b,c,d,e]
arr2 = [c,d,e]
```

I want to give array arr1 except arr2.

Comment: Plz be clear Do you want to remove the objects of arr2 from arr1

Comment: You are probably talking about **lists**. Arrays are something else: http://docs.python.org/library/array.html

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, you're looking for a *difference* between two sets represented in lists. So how about using the Python `set`, which has a builtin difference operation (overloaded on the `-` operator)?

```
>>> 
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> arr2 = [3, 4, 9]
>>> set(arr) - set(arr2)
>>> sdiff = set(arr) - set(arr2)
>>> sdiff
set([1, 2, 5])
>>> list(sdiff)
[1, 2, 5]
>>>
```

It would be more convenient to have your information in a `set` in the first place, though. This operation suggests that a `set` better fits your application semantics than a `list`. On the other hand, if you may have duplicates in the lists, then `set` is not a good solution.

Comment: And in the end you should convert the result to list again ;)

Comment: @Eli this is nice, but has the downside that if there are repeated elements in the lists you will remove them. That is, `set([1, 2, 3, 3]) = set([1, 2, 3])`. It really depends on what the OP wants to do, but it should be pointed out.

Comment: @EliBendersky: List comprehension is definitely faster than all these set conversions. From my experience, using sets only makes sense (in terms of runtime) if you are dealing with sets from the beginning (i.e. you don't have to convert to sets before). Unfortunately we don't know more about the context of code. Set might be the right data structure for the problem anyway.

Comment: @Felix: you're right, some measurements show the sets are about 50% slower with conversion happening both ways

Answer (score 2):

So you want the difference of two lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 77]

def list_difference(list1, list2):
    """uses list1 as the reference, returns list of items not in list2"""
    diff_list = []
    for item in list1:
        if not item in list2:
            diff_list.append(item)
    return diff_list

print list_difference(list1, list2)  # [5, 9, 10]
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
# simpler using list comprehension
diff_list = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]

print diff_list    # [5, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Even prettier: `if item not in list2`. +1 for the comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about (1) preserving the order in which the items appear and (2) efficiency in the case where your lists are large, you probably want a hybrid of the two solutions already proposed.

```
list2_items = set(list2)
[x for x in list1 if x not in list2_items]
```

(Converting both to sets will lose the ordering. Using `if x not in list2` in your list comprehension will give you in effect an iteration over both lists, which will be inefficient if `list2` is large.)

If you know that `list2` is not very long and don't need to save every possible microsecond, you should probably go with the simple list comprehension proposed by Flavius: it's short, simple and says exactly what you mean.